# partition permutation and combinations

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways , you can distribute 31 distinct chocolates to 5 persons, such that every one gets odd number of chocolates?( Repetition not allowed)

Comment: are the chocolates identical?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as giving $31-5$ chocolates to $5$ persons such that everyone gets an even amount.

This is the same as giving $13$ pairs to $5$ students.

This is $\binom{13+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{17}{4}=2380$

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the chocolates are all different, and that "repetition is not allowed" means that each person gets a different number of chocolates.

Start with $1+3+5+7+9=25$, and then there are $6$ left to distribute. The possible results are $$1+3+5+7+15\\1+3+5+9+13\\1+3+7+9+11$$
found by adding $(0,0,6),\ (0,2,4),$ or $(2,2,2)$ to the last three terms in the sum.

For each of these distributions, there are $5!$ ways to assign them to the people, so the answer is $$5!\left(\binom{31}{1,3,5,7,15}+\binom{31}{1,3,5,9,13}+\binom{31}{1,3,7,9,11}\right)$$which is $3067131463460064000$.

(If repetition were allowed, the answer would be $31!$ times the coefficient of $x^{31}$ in the Maclaurin expansion of $\sinh^5 x$, or $291038111544400697400$.)